# Preventing visor from fogging

Tags: motorcycle

How do you prevent your visor from fogging?

I ordered a pinlock today for my HJC helmet, but had read some good things about NEC pinkstick (some kind of wax for visor). Usually I just keep the visor open a bit, but during rain that is not an option.

Comment: @Joel Spolsky, my day is complete.  I've seen Joel edit a car maintenance question.  Now, if only he would integrate oil changing into Fogbugz 9....

Comment: This is so far off topic I can't even see it anymore!

Comment: @Styne666, I can see both sides of the issue - clearly it didn't strike me as off-topic last March.  I would certainly consider a poorly working defroster / defogger to be a problem in my car.  The fact that the OP is asking about a tiny windshield in front of his face is an analagous situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RainX makes an anti-fog product specifically for use on windshields, but I don't see why you couldn't use it on a helmet visor too.  To be honest, in my experience using it on windshields it doesn't work all that well, but it's better than nothing.

Alternatively there is a wide variety of anti-fog solutions made for scuba diving masks that I have had a lot of success with in those applications.

The key to using any of these products, whether it be RainX or something else is to make sure the interior surface is crystal clean. Toothpaste actually makes an excellent polish/cleanser for these types of surfaces.  Put a small dab on the inside of the visor and then scrub with wet fingers for a minute or two.  Rinse with clean water and lightly dry with a paper towel.  Avoid getting any oils or other chemical residue on the surface after it's clean.

Comment: The toothpaste thing was a new one. I was always trying to clean the interior part of the visor with specialized sprays or washing liquid, but it always gets greasy somehow. Tried toothpaste and it's keeping clean for now.

Comment: Mr Sheen furniture polish works comparably to RainX in making water bead away and reducing fog. It still needs to be reapplied periodically and does not totally cure fogging however I hear you can use it on Iridium coated visors.Pinlock inserts supposedly reduce fog dramatically as long as they are installed correctly.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for Pinlock inserts - I've had them on every helmet I've had and they're very effective.

As a cheaper alternative, a friend used to smear a small amount of washing-up liquid on the inside of his visor and said that worked really well too. Haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: the only problem with pinlocks is that the top edge can be right in your line of sight (specially on my HJC) however, I wouldnt ride without em now.

Answer (score 4):

My Shoei has a front vent which points up towards the visor which takes care of the problem at speed.  When those pesky red lights and stop signs come up I just crack the visor open.

Rain hasn't ever been an issue for me, as I'm in SoCal and we don't believe in rain.

Answer (score 2):

I use FogCity stick on "inserts" in my racing helmets.  Makes a world of difference.  Got a helmet that has now reached retirement age and the insert is still working like new!  Much better than a wax/liquid that needs to be reapplied occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way, or if you have no other options is to simply spit on the visor and smear it with your finger . It gets between the water molecules and prevents them to “hold” each other and spread.

I know it doesn't sounds good , but it works !

Comment: Indeed.  It actually works really good.